# Bootloop if -writable-system is used

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I used to start my Android Studio emulator using

```
emulator -avd "mydevice" -writable-system
```

But suddenly now it only works if I remove the `-writable-system` option, otherwise it is stuck with the boot logo.

Why would that option change the outcome of booting?

And how can I understand what happened, in order to fix this and make the `-writable-system` option work again?

In the worst case, is there a way to reset the system image without erasing the user data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the end I solved the problem by myself...

The cause of the problem was a corrupted system partition.

I went in my AVD folder and renamed system image file `system.img.qcow2` into `BACKUP_system.img.qcow2` (I could also have deleted it, but you never know).

Then, once I ran the emulator with option `-writable-system`, since it could not find the system image file anymore, then it created a new one and now it is possible to write on the system partition again.

And this also allowed me to avoid erasing the user data partition, therefore I saved the data and it's like nothing bad ever happened.

**The reason why it was still working without the `-writable-system` option:**

When I removed the `system.img.qcow2` file, initially I tried to run the emulator *without* the `-writable-system`. Again, it worked... and *no new system image file was generated*.

I tried to investigate on this, and when running:

```
emulator -help-disk-images
```

I noticed it says:

```
If you use a virtual device, its content directory should store
all writable images, and read-only ones will be found from the
corresponding platform/add-on directories.
```

So this is why the emulator was still working without the `-writable-system` option, although the system image file was corrupted. It's because that was a *writable image file*, so it's not loaded if the `-writable-system` option is not used, and the *read-only* system image, which is stored in a different place, is loaded instead.

And of course, when the emulator needs to create a new writable system partition (like in this case), it copies it from that read-only system image.